# $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{2^p}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all prime numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, number-theory

Recall $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^n}=1$.

Denote $\mathbb{P}$ as the set of all prime numbers.

Can one compute $\sum_{p\in\mathbb{P}} \frac{1}{2^p}$, or just approximate?

To generalize, let $C>0$ be some absolute constant, and fix $\alpha \in (0,1)$.

If $\phi:\mathbb{N}\to[0,\infty)$ is an increasing function (sequence), then how "slow" can $\phi$ grow such that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}C(\alpha)^{\phi(n)}$ converges? I understand the $C$ plays no role in the convergence of the sum, I just like it there.

Obviously, if $\phi$ grows linearly then we are fine, but if $\phi$ is constant then the series diverges. But what if $\phi$ grows logarithmically or some other slow growing function? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This converges quickly , so a very good numerical approximation is no problem , however I doubt that there is a "closed-form" expression for the value.

Comment: It's easy to compute the sum, over the primes, of $2^{-p}$; it's $0.01101010001010001010001000001\dots$ – of course, that's in base two. And you get an approximation by cutting it off after a finite number of bits.

Comment: Please don't use one post to ask two very different questions.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678985/42969

Comment: There is some information about this number at https://oeis.org/A051006

Answer (score 2):

$$S_m=\sum _{n=1}^m 2^{-p_n}$$ It would amazing to compute it using the binary representation of the prime numbers.

Nevertheless, it converges very fast to

$$0.41468250985111166024810962215430770836
57742381379169778682\cdots$$ which is [the prime constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_constant).

Answer (score 0):

If $\phi$ grows asymptotically like $c \log(n)$, then $\alpha^{\phi(n)}=\alpha^{c\log_\alpha(n)\log(\alpha)}=n^{c\log(\alpha)}.$ This is just a p-series, and will thus converge if $c\log(\alpha)<-1$, or if $c>-\frac{1}{\log(\alpha)}$. If it grows faster than logarithmic, then it can be bounded by this and will converge, and if it grows slower than it will not converge.

Comment: $\phi$ does not have to take integer values

Comment: My fault; I didn't see that the OP asked two very different questions.